# How to get JSON key and value and select certain values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm attempting to extract JSON key-value pairs from a GitHub public URL API (Ryanair) to display specific values in HTML, but I'm encountering difficulties. I have JSON data stored in the "data" variable, and I'm currently printing all of it. However, my goal is to extract only certain key values.

JSON structure:

```
{
  "total": 1,
  "arrivalAirportCategories": null,
  "fares": [
    {
      "outbound": {
        "departureAirport": {
          "countryName": "Italia",
          "iataCode": "CTA",
          "name": "Catania",
          "seoName": "catania",
          "city": {
            "name": "Catania",
            "code": "CATANIA",
            "countryCode": "it"
          }
        },
        "arrivalAirport": {
          "countryName": "Hungría",
          "iataCode": "BUD",
          "name": "Budapest",
          "seoName": "budapest",
          "city": {
            "name": "Budapest",
            "code": "BUDAPEST",
            "countryCode": "hu"
          }
        },
        "departureDate": "2021-12-28T19:45:00",
        "arrivalDate": "2021-12-28T21:50:00",
        "price": {
          "value": 60,
          "valueMainUnit": "60",
          "valueFractionalUnit": "00",
          "currencyCode": "EUR",
          "currencySymbol": "€"
        },
        "flightKey": "FR~6279~ ~~CTA~12/28/2021 19:45~BUD~12/28/2021 21:50~~",
        "flightNumber": "FR6279",
        "sellKey": "0~C~ ~FR~CZ7LOW~BND7~~0~14~~X",
        "previousPrice": {
          "value": 60,
          "valueMainUnit": "60",
          "valueFractionalUnit": "00",
          "currencyCode": "EUR",
          "currencySymbol": "€"
        },
        "priceUpdated": 1630397463
      },
      "inbound": {
        "departureAirport": {
          "countryName": "Hungría",
          "iataCode": "BUD",
          "name": "Budapest",
          "seoName": "budapest",
          "city": {
            "name": "Budapest",
            "code": "BUDAPEST",
            "countryCode": "hu"
          }
        },
        "arrivalAirport": {
          "countryName": "Italia",
          "iataCode": "CTA",
          "name": "Catania",
          "seoName": "catania",
          "city": {
            "name": "Catania",
            "code": "CATANIA",
            "countryCode": "it"
          }
        },
        "departureDate": "2022-01-04T17:10:00",
        "arrivalDate": "2022-01-04T19:15:00",
        "price": {
          "value": 60,
          "valueMainUnit": "60",
          "valueFractionalUnit": "00",
          "currencyCode": "EUR",
          "currencySymbol": "€"
        },
        "flightKey": "FR~6278~ ~~BUD~01/04/2022 17:10~CTA~01/04/2022 19:15~~",
        "flightNumber": "FR6278",
        "sellKey": "0~C~ ~FR~CZ7LOW~BND7~~0~13~~X",
        "previousPrice": {
          "value": 60,
          "valueMainUnit": "60",
          "valueFractionalUnit": "00",
          "currencyCode": "EUR",
          "currencySymbol": "€"
        },
        "priceUpdated": 1630395258
      },
      "summary": {
        "price": {
          "value": 120,
          "valueMainUnit": "120",
          "valueFractionalUnit": "00",
          "currencyCode": "EUR",
          "currencySymbol": "€"
        },
        "previousPrice": {
          "value": 120,
          "valueMainUnit": "120",
          "valueFractionalUnit": "00",
          "currencyCode": "EUR",
          "currencySymbol": "€"
        },
        "newRoute": false,
        "tripDurationDays": 7
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 1
}
```

I would like have access to these values:

```
fares.outbound.departureAirport.name;
fares.outbound.arrivalAirport.name;
fares.outbound.departureDate;
fares.outbound.price.value
```

Comment: Pay attention to the data you actually have. You can't just **ignore** arrays!

Comment: `fares.outbound` which fare are you trying to access?

Comment: departureAirport.name; arrivalAirport.name; departureDate; price.value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fares` is an array so,

```
fares.forEach((fare) => {
  console.log(fare.outbound.departureAirport.name);
  console.log(fare.outbound.arrivalAirport.name);
  console.log(fare.outbound.departureDate);
  console.log(fare.outbound.price.value);
})
```

Comment: I receive "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null". That's what I did: "var fares = JSON.parse(data);" where data is getJSON() return. Why is the JSON null when I use parse()?

Comment: if you do `fares =` the variable contains the entire object. So you would have to do `fares.fares.forEach(...)`

Comment: If the answer helped you, then I would appreciate accepting it as correct (from the controls to the upper-left of the question).

Comment: Iterate through the array using a foreach worked.